# Grouped UITableView Autolayout based section headers

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uitableviewsectionheader

So just like `UITableViewCell`s, I wanted to create section headers who can provide their own height using Autolayout constraints. I used `estimatedSectionHeaderHeight` and `sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` on `UITableView`.

It seems to work pretty well, except for when I want to hide the section header entirely. As soon as I set the height constraint to anything below `0.3`, the header resets to default height of `17.67`. I've tried returning `CGFloat.leastNonZeroMagnitude` as suggested by many people. But it still resets to default height.

I have to return at least 0.5 px height for constraints to work.

The header view is simply a view with top,left,right,bottom constraints to superview, and a height constraint that I change as required.

I am not implementing `heightForHeaderViewInSection` because I want autolayouts to take precedence in determining header view height.

**EDIT**
It's a Grouped UITableView.

**Update**
My only solution so far is to implement `heightForHeaderViewInSection` and return either `CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude` or `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` depending upon if I need to hide the `headerView` or let autolayouts decide its height when it's non-zero.

Comment: Are you returning the "auto-sizing" view in `viewForHeaderInSection`? If so, do you know at that point that you want it hidden? If so, you can return `nil` instead of returning a view at all...

Comment: returning nil results in default section header height.

Comment: An option is to just create the section header logic as cells